# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object error on one page but not on the other

Tags: php, mysql

I have a funcs.php file and that contains a function as follows:

```
function fetchProductDetails($id)
{
    global $mysqli;

        $column = "id";
        $data = $id;



    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        id,
        product_name,
        price,
        tags,
        summary,
        description
        FROM products
        WHERE
        $column = ?
        ");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $data);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$productName,$price,$tags,$summary,$description);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row = array('id' => $id, 'productName' => $productName, 'price' =>$price,'tags' => $tags, 'summary' => $summary, 'description' => $description);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $row;
}
```

Now when I call the function on a new page, it doesn't give any error. But when I call this function on some other page, this gives an error:

```
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
```

To call the function, I wrote the following code:

```
include '../funcs.php';
//Product ID
$id = 1;
//Product details into a single variable..
$productDetails = fetchProductDetails($id);

//Product Name
$productName = $productDetails['productName'];
// Product Summary...
$productSummary = $productDetails['summary'];
//Product price..
$productPrice = $productDetails['price'];

//Product Description
$productDescription = $productDetails['description'];
```

On printing the following, why am I getting this error.? Why am I not getting error when I write the same code on the other page.?

Comment: If you get an error about `prepare on a non object`, this means that the `object` (which in this case is `$mysqli`) is not actually an object. I see you're using a `global $mysqli` but are you sure that it's set? Dump that variable and make sure it's correct.

Comment: sure like to know how/where you're connecting. and make sure you chose the right db and table.

Comment: You might want to consider putting the database connection right into the function parameters instead of using global variables. Something like: `function fetchProductDetails($id, mysqli $dbh)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a declaration of `$mysqli` in your code before you call `fetchProductDetails($id)`. You need a line before that like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
```

where the variables passed to the constructor are whatever your database credentials are.